# Selection of unique characters

Tags: c, arrays, char, concatenation

Please, help with the code.

Requirement:
Write a function my_union that takes two strings and returns, without doubles, the characters that appear in either one of the strings.

Example:
Input: "zpadinton" && "paqefwtdjetyiytjneytjoeyjnejeyj"
Output: "zpadintoqefwjy"

My code:

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char *my_union(char *a, char *b) {
  char *str;
  // Algorithm for excluding nonunique characters from string a(given in
  // parameters).
  str[0] = a[0];
  int k = 1;
  str[k] = '\0';
  for (int i = 1; a[i] != '\0'; i++) {
    bool is = true;
    for (int j = 0; str[j] != '\0'; j++) {
      if (str[j] == a[i]) {
        is = false;
        break;
      }
    }
    if (is) {
      str[k] = a[i];
      k++;
      str[k] = '\0';
    }
  } // In this case we are  excluding excess character 'n' from "zpadinton", so
    // str is equal to "zpadinto".

  // Algorithm for adding unique characters from array b(given in parameters)
  // into str.
  for (int i = 0; b[i] != '\0'; i++) {
    bool is = true;
    for (int j = 0; str[j] != '\0'; j++) {
      if (str[j] == b[i]) {
        is = false;
        break;
      }
    }
    if (is) {
      strncat(str, &b[i], 1);
    }
  }
  return str;
}
```

The first algorithm is almost identical with second, but it doesn't work(. Mb I messed up with memory, give some advice, pls.

Comment: the `str` pointer does not point anywhere valid

Comment: @Nurdaulet_mit22 Could you provide a more readable example of strings? For example it is unclear why the character 'p' is present in the result string when it is present in the both source strings.

Answer (score 2):

If you mean, get the unique characters from two strings and store them into a new string, try this code ;

First, you must allocate a memory for str. In your code, str is not pointing allocated memory location, so you will probably get segmentation fault.

```
int contains(const char * str,char c)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(str); ++i)
        if(str[i] == c)
            return 1;

    return 0;
}

char * my_union(char *a, char*b)
{

    char * res = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*(strlen(a) + strlen(b)));

    int pushed = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(a); ++i)
    {
        if(!contains(res,a[i])){
            res[pushed] = a[i];
            pushed++;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(b); ++i)
    {
        if(!contains(res,b[i])){
            res[pushed] = b[i];
            pushed++;
        }
    }

    return res;
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{

    char string1[9] = "abcdefgh";
    char string2[9] = "abegzygj";

    char * result = my_union(string1,string2);
    printf("%s\n", result);

    return 0;
}
```

Also, do not forget the free the return value of my_union after you done with it.